# Search for 2 files and delete them VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm building a script that searches inside the office install directory for 2 *.dot files (1.dot & 2.dot) if it finds them it deletes them.

How would I manage that? it has to be in VBScript

Notes: I've got it searching for the installed office version and it returns the base install path (IE: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office %Version%) So i would need it to search from there for the files.

Here is what I'm currently using to find these files (but with no luck - it returns all *.dot files)

```
dim sFilename

Dim objDict
Set objDict=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
sFilename = ""

fileLocation=Session.Property("OFFICEPATH") 'this is a stored path from InstallShield = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office %Version%\

Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Call Recurse(fileLocation)



ItemArray = objDict.Items


For i = 0 To objDict.count -1
    sFilename = sFilename & ItemArray(i) & VBCRLF
Next 

msgbox(sFilename)

'find a specific file by name and return path 
if objDict.Exists("1.dot") then 
    msgbox(objDict.Item("1.dot")) 
end if

'find a specific file by name and return path 
if objDict.Exists("2.dot") then 
    msgbox(objDict.Item("2.dot")) 
end if


Sub Recurse(strFolderPath)
    Dim objFolder
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    Dim objFile
    Dim objSubFolder

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If (InStr(objFile.Name, ".") > 0) Then

            If (LCase(Mid(objFile.Name, InStrRev(objFile.Name, "."))) = ".dot") Then 
                if objDict.Exists(objFile.Name)=false then 
                objDict.Add objFile.Name,objfile.Path 
                End if 
            End if 
        End If 
    Next

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Call Recurse(objSubFolder.Path)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Share what you have until now

Comment: Are you saying your second and third message boxes aren't displaying the paths to `1.dot` and `2.dot`?

Comment: correct (i've not added the delete function in yet - was wanting to make sure the paths where correct, but yes, they dont show the paths)

Comment: Do they appear in the first message box? If you navigate to the folders via Windows Explorer, can you see the `.dot` files?

Comment: yes they show in the 1st message box, but not the 2nd or 3rd and yes, those files exist!

Comment: Dictionaries are case-sensitive by default. Are you sure they're not named `1.DOT` and `2.DOT`?

Comment: nah - i figured it out (answer in next post)

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't make sense. You said they appeared in the first message box, though, so they _were_ getting picked up.

Comment: doesn't make sense to me either, but after adding "\" to the end it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - this:

```
fileLocation=Session.Property("OFFICEPATH")
```

Needed a trailing slash:

```
fileLocation=Session.Property("OFFICEPATH")+"\"
```

For some reason the files where not being picked up without the trailing slash.